# Limit Word Count of A Textfield in JQuery

Tags: jquery, word-count

I'm modding some jquery code to limit the word count of a textfield but I can't figure out how to get the value. Here's the code:

```
    <script>

var $limitWords = 20;
var $wordCount = $('#count').val();

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#edit-field-message-0-value").keyup(function() {
         $('#count').html($('#edit-field-message-0-value').val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length);

      if ($wordCount > $limitWords) {
      $('#edit-field-message-0-value').addClass('error');
      } else {
      $('#edit-field-message-0-value').addClass('not-error');
      }
      });
    });

</script>
```

Specifically, what should "$wordCount" be equal to to return the current value?

I think it should be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Scott

Comment: Borrow the code from SO's comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the $wordCount variable.  I believe you may be trying to do the following:

```
$("#edit-field-message-0-value").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;

    if (wordcount > $limitWords) {
        $this.addClass('error');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('not-error');
    } 
});
```

I am also going to presume you wanted to store the current count:

```
$("#edit-field-message-0-value").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
    if (wordcount > $limitWords) {
        $('#count').html($limitWords);
        $this.addClass('error');
    } else {
        $('#count').html(wordcount);
        $this.addClass('not-error');
    } 
});
```

Comment: I can't mark both your answer and Russ Cam's answer but thanks for point this out for me. Basically, I needed to create an event handler to define the wordcount variable.

Comment: Here space is taken as a word.and hence alter the idea of word count

Answer (score 2):

The following script won't let you enter more than `limitWord`:

```
var limitWord = 20;
var maxchars = 0;
$("#edit-field-message-0-value").keyup(function() {
   $this = $(this);
   var wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length - 1;
   if (wordcount < limitWord) {
      chars = $this.val().length;
    }
   else{
    var text = $(this).val();
    var new_text = text.substr(0,chars);
    $(this).val(new_text);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just expanding on the above, great answer from Pritam, I found it behaved quite oddly and changed

`var wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,.-:;]*/).length - 1;`

To:

`var wordcount = jQuery.trim($this.val()).split(/\b[\s,.-:;]*/).length;`

This sorts the quirky wordcount behaviour (if you're displaying the value back to the user for feedback)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you need to put the code to get the value inside an event handler for the input/textarea, for example in an event handler foe the keypress event. This way you can restrict the number of words whilst the user is entering text into the input/textarea.

Comment: I can't mark both your answer and cballou answer correct but thanks for point this out for me. Basically, I needed to create an event handler to define the wordcount variable - cballou's answer has an example.

Makes perfect since. Thanks Russ Cam!

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what the "#count" element is, I took the queue from the method that sets the value using html(...).  So, this should work:

```
var $wordCount = $('#count').html();
```