# Limit length of textarea in Words using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have the following bind on keyup which alerts if they go over 150 characters, but you can just press okay and keep typing and then just keep pressing okay.

I want to crop them at 150 words (not characters) and if they type over it, remove the extras. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it, I can figure out characters. But not words.

```
jQuery('textarea').keyup(function() {
      var $this, wordcount;
      $this = $(this);
      wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
      if (wordcount > 150) {
        jQuery(".word_count span").text("150");
        return alert("You've reached the maximum allowed words.");
      } else {
        return jQuery(".word_count span").text(wordcount);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Do not rely on keyup/down alone. Also consider the case of the user doing a right-click -> paste or text drag and drop etc. Google for "jQuery textchanged event" and you will find whats needed.

Comment: So what should I rely on? Right click paste triggers a key up... and I have no idea what text drag drop is.

Comment: Correction, testing on Windows IE cut/paste didn't trigger key up. I'll change it to http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Comment: If I were to reach the limit you impose I_would_just_start_not_using_spaces_And_I_will_get_my_say_in_no_propblem

Comment: Elias, yah I know there are problems with it which is why I am not relying 100% on javascript, there is server side too. But I still want to crop it at X words and it has to be possible with javascript.

Comment: @Steven - Yeah, the zurb plugin's what i was referring to. You got it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579408/limit-word-count-of-a-textfield-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent the typing itself (when count > 150)  you can do as following:

- Use keypress instead of keyup
- Instead of `return alert()` first do an `alert()` and then `return false;`

You may also want to add change (or blur) event handler to handle text pasting.

```
var maxWords = 150;
jQuery('textarea').keypress(function() {
    var $this, wordcount;
    $this = $(this);
    wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
    if (wordcount > maxWords) {
        jQuery(".word_count span").text("" + maxWords);
        alert("You've reached the maximum allowed words.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return jQuery(".word_count span").text(wordcount);
    }
});

jQuery('textarea').change(function() {
    var words = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
    if (words.length > maxWords) {
        words.splice(maxWords);
        $(this).val(words.join(""));
        alert("You've reached the maximum allowed words. Extra words removed.");
    }
});​
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qPvch/)

Comment: The first one works the second one doesn't work. If you change it to bind on paste the extra words are removed but so are all the spaces.

Comment: I'm going to give you the accepted question because the first example solves my problem. *The second example does not work as it should though, just a note for others.*

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * jQuery.textareaCounter
 * Version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) 2011 c.bavota - http://bavotasan.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * Date: 10/20/2011
**/
(function($){
    $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
        // setting the defaults
        // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
        var defaults = {
            limit: 100
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // and the plugin begins
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj, text, wordcount, limited;

            obj = $(this);
            obj.after('<span style="font-size: 11px; clear: both; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" id="counter-text">Max. '+options.limit+' words</span>');

            obj.keyup(function() {
                text = obj.val();
                if(text === "") {
                    wordcount = 0;
                } else {
                    wordcount = $.trim(text).split(" ").length;
                }
                if(wordcount > options.limit) {
                    $("#counter-text").html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                    limited = $.trim(text).split(" ", options.limit);
                    limited = limited.join(" ");
                    $(this).val(limited);
                } else {
                    $("#counter-text").html((options.limit - wordcount)+' words left');
                } 
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Load that up and then you can use the following to make it work:

```
$("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
```

http://bavotasan.com/2011/simple-textarea-word-counter-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, but this seems to be the only one that actually worked.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, but need to add unique id for every label of word count when used on multiple textarea element e.g.  cntid=obj.attr('id')+"-counter_label",  this will get the id of each textarea and use to define id of the counter label.

Answer (score 1):

Check [jQuery: Count words in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time)
and this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/YJVPZ/1/

Then, if you want to cut the extra words... you could do something like:

```
var maxWords = 10;
if(finalCount > maxWords){
    $("#a").val(a.value.slice(0,-2)); // the -2 is to remove the extra space at the end
};
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/YJVPZ/80/

Hope it helps, Good Luck!

Comment: If you keep trying to type it adds parts of the word and continues on typing. So basically doesn't work.

Comment: ¿?... can't reproduce the issue you mention, not in CR, FF or IE. If I continue typing, the script delete the extra word and trailing space... Maybe you say that if you continue typing right next to the last word, adds and put all letters together. If this is what you saying,  that's normal, is because is considerer as a one word. Anyway... doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. The `value` argument should be your textarea value.

```
jQuery('textarea').val();


function wordcount(value)
{
    value = value.replace(/\s+/g," ");
    var andchr = value.split(" & ").length - 1;
    var char_count = value.length;
    var fullStr = value + " ";                      

    //word count for regional language
    v = value.split(' ');
    var word_count1 = v.length;                         
    var cheArr = Array('@','.','"',"'",'_','-','+','=',';','&','*','\(','\)','{','}','[','}','|','\\','\,','/');                            
    for(i=0; i<=cheArr.length; i++)
    {
        word_count1 = word_count1 + value.split(cheArr[i]).length - 1;
    } 

    //word count for all languages
    var initial_whitespace_rExp = /^[^A-Za-z0-9]+/gi;
    var left_trimmedStr = fullStr.replace(initial_whitespace_rExp, "");                     
    var non_alphanumerics_rExp = rExp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/gi;

    var cleanedStr = left_trimmedStr.replace(non_alphanumerics_rExp, " ");                      
    var splitString = cleanedStr.split(" ");                        
    var word_count = (splitString.length - 1) + andchr;                          
    if(word_count1 > word_count)
    {
        word_count = word_count1;
    }                       
    if(value == '' || value == null || typeof(value) == 'undefined'){
        word_count = 0;
    }

    alert(word_count);

}
```

Comment: This had the same problem that my original code had (didn't crop extra characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
         var obj = $(this);
         var maxLen = 150;
         var val = obj.val();
         var chars = val.length;
         if(chars > maxLen){
              obj.val(val.substring(0,maxLen));
         }
});
```

Comment: Crops at 150 characters, not 150 words.

Answer (score -1):

Register to these events:

```
$('textarea').on('paste cut keydown', function(){...});
```